Does Shimano document the tool sizes for their parts?
I need to know the cone wrench size for my front hub. And I thought maybe Shimano documents the tools required for their parts.
Example: Shimano HB M8000 Deore XT front hub
https://dassets.shimano.com/content/dam/global/cg1SHICCycling/final/ev/ev/EV-HB-M8000-3868.pdf

Questions

Does Shimano document the tool sizes required?

If not maybe somebody knows which size cone wrench in this specific case, for Shimano HB M8000 Deore XT (front hub)?
Some points

It's bigger than 16mm because I have 16mm and that is too small.
I measured the nut and it seems like 16mm to 17mm.
I looked up the Lock Nut Unit "Y26J98020" and the Hub Axle Unit "Y2UB98030" online. But I could not any tool specifications.


They do document this, and the main place is in the Dealer Manual (DM) pdfs they release. In this era they are all freely available at si.shimano.com (Shimano has done the sharing of their technical service info in less readily accessible to the public ways over the years, but for a long time now it's all been there).
For most of their components, more than one model is rolled into the same DM document, but the info will be in there somewhere, perhaps under a heading shared with multiple models that all have the same procedures/tools or nearly. Here's the page for HB-M8000 in DM-HB0002-15:

This shows that according to them you need a 5mm Allen and their TL-HS22, which you then Google to break out of Shimano logic world and see it's their double-ended 17mm and 24mm cone wrench originally made for Saint. You then use inference to know you're using the 17mm end on this hub.

All cones I've encountered are in the range of 13-17mm.  So if you know yours are >16mm, then that would leave 17mm as the likely size.
If you are an aspiring bike mechanic, it never hurts to own a caliper for measuring things like this.
